# Django Rest Framework Hiding the JSON data

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have just started learning Django Rest Framework. I want to hide the api that is visible when we go to its url so that no one can see any data whenever they enter that url. I just need the url to post data (for ex- from a membership form...name email and stuff). How can I achieve this. Most of the questions here only talk about hiding browsable api for which they use JSONRenderer but I want to remove the JSON completely. Please do tell if I am thinking in the wrong direction. The idea behind this is that I don't want the information I ask from a user to be visible to everyone through that url. I tried achieving this in the following way. Is this a fine way of doing this or is this going to mess up the application, because I don't see any errors and the post requests are working. I am using React for the frontend. This is my first time posting a question. Please tell if you need any other information. Thanks a lot in advance.

I have only done this in the first **if** block {if request.method == 'GET':}, I returned a string instead of serializer.data and now whenever i go to membershipform/  it just shows "serializer.data" instead of all the objects.

**views.py**

```
class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return 

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
def memberform_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        memberform = Memberform.objects.all()
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(memberform, many=True)
        return Response("serializer.data")

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            # creating a membershipid
            fid = instance.id
            strid = str(fid)
            temp = '{:>06}'
            if len(strid) <= 6:
                memstrid = temp.format(strid)
            else:
                memstrid = strid
            memyear = str(instance.created_at.year)
            memtype = instance.membership_type[0]
            memid = memyear + memtype + memstrid
            instance.membership_id = memid
            instance.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@authentication_classes([CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
def memberform_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        memberform = Memberform.objects.get(pk=pk)

    except Memberform.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(memberform)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(memberform, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        memberform.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**models.py**

```
class Memberform(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    membership_id = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    alt_email = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    institute_university = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    institute_city = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    institute_state = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    institute_pincode = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    permanent_address_city = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    permanent_address_state = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    permanent_address_pincode = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    official_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    membership_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    research_interests = models.CharField(max_length=1500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Also I want to create a membership id which follows a format of year membership_type and id(pk) (for ex: 2021B000001) so I implemented it in the **POST method if block**. Is this a correct way of doing this or is there any other way? Thanks a lot for your help. Any suggestions would be helpful as I am still learning Django and feel like I am just brute forcing through stuff.

**EDIT:** This is the updated models.py and views.py

**models.py**

```
class Memberform(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    membership_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    membership_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....rest of the fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        strid = str(self.id)
        if len(strid) <= 6:
            memstrid = '{:>06}'.format(strid)
        else:
            memstrid = strid
        memyear = str(datetime.datetime.now().year)
        memtype = self.membership_type[0] if self.membership_type else ""
        memid = memyear + memtype + memstrid
        self.membership_id = memid
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
def memberform_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        memberform = Memberform.objects.all()
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(memberform, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@authentication_classes([CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
def memberform_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        memberform = Memberform.objects.get(pk=pk)

    except Memberform.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(memberform)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = MemberformSerializer(memberform, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        memberform.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

This is the response I'm getting when I do a post request,
**response after post request**

```
created_at: "2021-05-14T02:29:21.105382Z"
id: 31
membership_id: "2021S00None"
membership_type: "Silver"
...rest of the data
```

The membership_id is **2021S00None** , here None is supposed to be the id(pk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to access the `Memberform` list but only to create a `Memberform` for that view, you can remove the `'GET'` from the supported methods of your view:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
def memberform_list(request):
    serializer = MemberformSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = serializer.save()
        # creating a membershipid
        # [...]
```

Regarding your `membership_id` field built from the date, id and type fields, what you did will probably work, but if you don't need that behavior only for this specific view but always for your model, you can do it at the model level instead, by [overriding predefined `save()` model method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods). This way you will not have to repeat that field creation for other views creating a `Memberform` object.

```py
class Memberform(models.Model):
    # your fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.membership_id:
            strid = str(self.id)
            if len(strid) <= 6:
                memstrid = '{:>06}'.format(strid)
            else:
                memstrid = strid
            memyear = str(self.created_at.year)
            memtype = self.membership_type[0] if self.membership_type else ""
            memid = memyear + memtype + memstrid
            self.membership_id = memid
            member_form = Memberform.objects.get(id=self.id)
            member_form.membership_id = self.membership_id
            member_form.save()
```

Comment: Indeed, `auto_now_add` adds the current date only after the save method. I have updated the code to make it work with a call to `datetime.datetime.now()` instead of using the value of your `created_at` field. This seems safe enough to me as you only need the year.

Comment: Actually `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` works for me too.

Comment: The save method is not working. It gives an error: membership_id cannot be null even though I have specified null=True. So, I gave it a default value and now it updates but the id part is always None. So I called self.save() once in the beginning so that it can get a pk. Now membership_id just saves with the default value. I have updated my models.py. Could this be happening because of the save method called in views.py? Sorry deleted my previous comment cuz i solved it and then realized you had already answered.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem. I have tried with a simple example with just the model and a `save()` overridden method, and it doesn't need to be nullable. It gets the build value including the id. If you kept both setting the value at serializer level and at model level, you have to remove that in one of them.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my problem clearly. I have updated my post with the new models.py and views.py, serializers.py remains same. The problem is that the id is being read as None. Please tell if you need any other information.

Comment: Actually you're right, I tested again and, neither `created_at` nor `id` are available in the `save` method when dealing with object creation. They are only available after calling the parent `save` method. I will try to find another way.

Comment: I have updated my code and it should work. I have made the call to the parent `save` first, and then I check if `membership_id` is not set (this is actually important because the `save` method is called on object creation and on object update, and we want to call it only on object creation), and in that condition I build the value (with `id` and `created_at` that are already available), and finally I query the database to find the object itself, and save it again to update the database values. But this solution seems not that elegant to me as it in some way calls `save` it itself...

Comment: This kind of thing should be at least well tested to avoid bad surprises like infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks finally solved it. Instead of using ```save()``` again I updated the instance. ```Memberform.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(membership_id=memid)``` thus avoiding the infinite recursion.

Comment: This returns membership_id as Null in the response but updates it to the required value soon after.